# print button is also print on myprint

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I unable to remove the print button from the hardcopy. Is there any other methods to remove the print button? i m using prime faces.

here is code

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['print']}" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print"
                        style="font-size:small;margin-left:94%;">
                        <p:printer target="tab1" />
                    </p:commandButton>
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is impossible to guess what your problem is, assuming that you know where escape/backspace keys are on a keyboard. If you really need help, reformulate the question so that your problem is clear to understand.

Comment: i think he want to hide the button when he print the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to remove any button when u print the page, u can simply use css by following the step below:

1. Set id to your button.
    `<p:commandButton id="btnPrint" ... />`
2. Simply include your `print.css` at the Head of your web page. Note
   that the media is now set to **print**.
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`
3. Hide your button by declaring **display: none;** in the CSS.
   `#btnPrint{display:none;}`

Comment: i am using primefaces only